# Subversion client for Windows (similar to Versions)

Tags: windows-7, software-development, version-control, subversion

I am a big fan of [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) ([Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) client for Mac OS). I'm looking for a Subversion client that can:

- work on Windows 7
- display the number of new commits that I haven't retrieved yet on several repositories, like this (the 2 in the yellow box next to main is the number of new commits):

  [image: Versions GUI]

Bonus point if:

- is free
- can perform an `svn update` and `svn commit` on several repositories at once
- can display the list of each file with the name of the last committer as well as the date of the last commit, e.g.:

  [image: Versions GUI]

Comment: So to clarify you are looking for a Win 7 compatible, preferably free, subversion GUI that can manage multiple repositories simultaneously?

Comment: Yes with the ability to display the number of new commits that I haven't retrieved yet on several repositories.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://tortoisesvn.net/ yet? It seems to be the standard for subversion on Windows (I use it all the time, but I haven't actually tried things like committing to multiple repo's at once, so I can't speak for those...)

Comment: @DylanCorriveau Yes that's the one I am using but as far as I know it cannot display the number of new commits that I haven't retrieved yet on several repositories.