# SVN Client compatability for Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, osx, version-control

Starting a new business venture.

I have always used VisualSVN as my SVN server and Tortoise SVN as my SVN client on Windows systems. This has always worked perfectly for me and my teams.

My new project is a two person team with a friend, who is a die hard Mac user and is my web designer for the project (I am backend, and they are front end).

At the end of the day, if I use VisualSVN as my server. Can I (as long as i use the same versions of svn) use tortoise for all my windows work, and have my friend use a different client on their Mac and both work on the same repositories on the same Visual SVN server?

If so does anyone have a SVN that they recommend out there for Mac? My friend has never used SVN before, but i made a pretty clear point for how it is useful and have them very interested in the version control concept.

The downloads page of tortoise SVN recommends Smart SVN for mac clients. Can anyone confirm this is a good choice, or any other clients that may be a recommended. Some forums recommend "Versions SVN" for Mac, but I have no idea of its compatibility.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) ([Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) client for Mac OS, it is compatible with any standard SVN server like I guess VisualSVN). The big pro of Versions is that along with the usual features of an SVN client (up, commit, diff, etc.), it displays the number of new commits that I haven't retrieved yet on several repositories, like this (the 2 in the yellow box next to main is the number of new commits):

[image]

[image]

(By the way I am looking for a [Versions for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2278/903). Any idea?)

Comment: I have personally only used tortoise and found it very good. It does not have a list of items that have not been retrieved yet though.